# Random array creation with specifc distribution and one more condition

Tags: python, arrays

I have to create a random (28x1) array (say N), where each element is a integer. N has to follow a distribution like Weibull or Beta, such that initial elements of N has higher values than the later elements. Also, there is another fixed (28x1) array, P. Now, \sum{N(i).P(i)} should be approximately equal to a fixed value say W.

Now, for each iteration W would change, so it should be mirrored by a change in N while retaining the similar distribution (not necessary to be exactly same). P is constant throughout.

Thanks.

Comment: Question is not really clear to me, but this might be a good start for you:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.weibull.html